Collecting Microsoft Teams SBC status using Graph API
I am trying to collect the latest SBC status for each direct routing profile for Microsoft Teams. Basically, I am looking for the same content as the "Health Dashboard for Direct Routing" on Microsoft Teams Admin portal.I could not find anything on Graph API. Does anyone know how to collect such info using Graph API or powershell?
Thanks
I scanned the Graph API documentation but the only thing I could find was direct routing call log.

Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/phone-system/direct-routing/sip-options-tls-certificate-issues

Currently, there isn't a direct way to collect the latest SBC status for each direct routing profile for Microsoft Teams using the Graph API or PowerShell that replicates the "Health Dashboard for Direct Routing" found in the Microsoft Teams Admin portal. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.

Thank you for taking time to respond folks. I will provide some feedback as suggested.
